# How to put a pair of unicode character in string.xml file android studio?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, unicode

How to put ✌️ victory hand character which have Unicode: U+270C U+FE0F, UTF-8: E2 9C 8C EF B8 8F in button using string.xml file in android studio.

Answer (score 3):

Put the HTML code for emoji you want to show.

```
<string name="victory">&#x270C;</string>
```

[Refer this site to get code for emojis](https://emojis.wiki)